# Many to Many relationship with amount row

Tags: typescript, database-design, mikro-orm

I have a to setup a minimal database scenario for one of my classes.
It's about creating a portfolio and storing your amount of coins in there.

I have set up a table for coins and a table for portfolios.
Each portfolio can have multiple coins and coins can be in multiple portfolios. So I setup a m:n relationship.

The question now is how I can store how high the amount of coins in one portfolio is? Cause the amount of coins in every portfolio is different.

Am I right, that I have to setup a third table with a another m:n relationship?
And if I have to how would the third table look like?
Since we are using mikro-orm and it is a m:n relationship it automatically created a third table named portfolio_coins

This is my code so far:

Portfolio.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Portfolio extends BaseEntity {
   @Property()
   name: string;

   @ManyToOne(() => User, { nullable: true, cascade: [] })
   owner?: User;

   @ManyToMany(() => Coin)
   coins = new Collection<Coin>(this);

   constructor({ name, owner }: CreatePortfolioDTO) {
       super();
       this.name = name;
       this.owner = owner;
   }
```

Coin.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Coin {
   @PrimaryKey()
   id: string;

   @Property()
   name: string;

   @Property()
   symbol: string;

   @Property()
   rank: number;

   @Property()
   marketCapUsd: number;

   @Property()
   priceUsd: number;

   @ManyToMany(() => Portfolio, (portfolio) => portfolio.coins)
   portfolios = new Collection<Portfolio>(this);

   constructor({ id, name, symbol, rank, marketCapUsd, priceUsd}: CreateCoinDTO) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
       this.symbol = symbol;
       this.rank = rank;
       this.marketCapUsd = marketCapUsd;
       this.priceUsd = priceUsd;
   }
```

We are working with typescript but I think that doesn't matter here since I should be able to implement it as soon as I have a plan how.

I hope it's understandable what my question here is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you stuck in what published presentation of what information modelling & design method? Also this is (clearly) a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If asking reflect research. [How much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] PS
"a third table with a another m:n relationship" But it's a 1:many relationship, a portfolio has 1 count.

Answer (score 0):

As you also need to store the amount of coins in a portfolio, you would indeed have to create a third table, and get rid of the `ManyToMany` relationship.

Call is something like `PortfolioDetail`.
Both Portfolio and Coin will have a `OneToMany` relationship to `PortfolioDetail`.

Next to storing the `portfolio` and `coin` in the `PortfolioDetail`'s table, you'll need a 3rd property which keeps track of the `quantity (or amount)`.